# JQuery update content in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use jquery ajax to get data from the PHP file.

```
data = <option>Peter</option><option>Maria</option>
```

I want to then use jquery to put this data after the first option

```
<select>
   <option>Name</option>
</select>
```

I cant use html() on select because then the first option will be deleted. what jquery function can I use to put them after the first one?

EDIT: i cannot use append because then when i make another request and the data is:

```
data = <option>Michael</option><option>Erik</option>
```

Peter and Maria will still be in the Select list. how can I do? I have tried to have a

```
<div id=addhere></div>
```

after the first option and then use html() but it doesn't work. Weird. how can I solve this?

Comment: @fayer it might be time to spend some quality time with the jQuery docs and learn more about the power of jQuery rather then having the people of StackOverflow develop you whole application one question at a time.

Comment: sometime i feel like the documentation is not that good. eg. it says using remove you can remove elements. but you have to give it a expression. so why dont they give me a link to a page with expressions so i can use them instead of letting me search for it...sorry for the angry comment...i have been coding too long and have lost a little patience:)

Comment: @fayer, I can understand frustration of reading docs. I personally thing the jQuery ones are somewhat clear, but you could also look at Cody Lindey's book, jQuery Enlightenment. It is packed full of examples.

Comment: thx for the tips. i will give the book a try!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the original options in a variable and append the AJAX response along with the original options.

### Working demo:

http://jsbin.com/otiro (editable via http://jsbin.com/otiro/edit)

### Source:

```
<select id="name">
  <option>Name</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var nameSelect = $('#name'), originalOptions = nameSelect.children();
  
  function handleAjaxResponse(response) {
    nameSelect.children().remove().end().append(originalOptions.add(response));
  }

  $.get("getNames.php", handleAjaxResponse);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Changing my response to answer your question after you've updated it...

So lets say you return the following via AJAX:

```
data = "<option>Michael</option><option>Erik</option>";
```

Then, you can merely update that data, and use html()

```
data = "<option>Name</option>" + data;
$("#selectToModify").html(data);
```

Here is the old answer, just for your reference:

```
$("#divToAddTo").append(data);
```

html() will replace the innerHTML of an element.
append() will append whatever data to the end of the innerHTML.

Comment: what is the difference between text() and innerhtml()?

Comment: i have updated the question so your answer wasn't correct anymore. so i unchecked it:)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but take a look at the [jQuery reference](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation) for the functions you can use to insert content. `insertAfter` may be the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

check out the [jQuery docs append](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append#content) function

Answer (score -2):

i used jquery remove function to remove all siblings to the first option before i appended new options...it worked great...=)